# Dropdown list in mvc having some issues

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two models called channels and programs.. in showing the dropdown of channels and all I want is that when I select any channel, the view will show the programs of the specific channel. Problem is when I select any channel, it takes the value of channel and return it to the controller and apply filtering logic and pass the data to the new View..Although the view is executing all values properly on the browser it is not visible.. any help would be grateful.

**View Code**:

```
@model SitefinityWebApp.Mvc.Models.Channel
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Title, Model.Items, "Select Channel-", new { @id = "ddl" })
<div id="myddl">        
</div>    
<script>    
$('#ddl').change(function () {
    var selectedValue = $('#ddl').val();
    $.post('@Url.Action("GetProgramByChannel", "Channels")', { selection : selectedValue }, function (data) {
    });
});
</script>
```

**GetProgramByChannel** Method Taking the selected value

```
public ActionResult GetProgramByChannel(string selection)
{
    var model = new ProgramsModel();
    return View("ProgramsByChannel", model.GetChildItemsOfChannel(selection));
}
```

**ProgramsByChannelView**

```
@model SitefinityWebApp.Mvc.Models.Channel
<div id="ddl">
    @foreach (var item in Model.Programs)
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Title) <br />
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.ShortDescription) <br />
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.LongDescription) <br />
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because,with your current code, when user make a selection on the dropdown, you are making an ajax call and the result (the new view result with channels will come as the response for this ajax call) is not being used anywhere.

Instead of doing the ajax call, you can make a new GET request to the action method which will return the view.

```
$('#ddl').change(function () {
    var v = $(this).val();
    var url ='@Url.Action("GetProgramByChannel", "Channels")?selection='+v;
    window.location.href=url;
});
```

If you do not want to issue a new GET request,but want to show the result in the same view, then all you have to do is update the DOM with the results coming back from the ajax call.

```
$('#ddl').change(function () {
    var v = $(this).val();
    var url ='@Url.Action("GetProgramByChannel", "Channels")';

    $.post(url, { selection : v} ,function(result){
      $("#myddl").html(result);  //update the myddl div
    });

});
```

Now you have to make sure that your action method return a view without layout as you are looking for the partial page result. You can use the `PartialView` method to do so.

```
public ActionResult GetProgramByChannel(string selection)
{
   var model = new ProgramsModel();
   return PartialView("ProgramsByChannel", model.GetChildItemsOfChannel(selection));
}
```

Also, I see you are overwriting the Id value of dropdown to `ddl`. Why would you do that ? What is wrong with `Title` being the Id value of the SELECT element ? If you do not override, the helper will generate the SELECT element with Title as the value of  `Id` and `name` attributes

Comment: Sorry that overriding was just by mistake.. and also Can u please explain how to update the DOM ?

Comment: That is the second part of answer. The one using `$.post`

Comment: i have update the script tag as per your answer .. and made a partial view .. rendered it in myddl div.. but no change

Comment: What is your requirement ? If you do not want to reload to a new page/view, use ajax, If you do not want the partial page update, then follow the first approach which is similar to navigating to a new page

Comment: the first approach worked fine..! thanks for that help but if im trying the second approach it is not working

Comment: Are you getting the expected result for the ajax call  ? Do you have a div with id `myddl` in the page ? Then it should work as long as you do not have any other script errors.

Comment: Try adding a `console.log(result);` inside the $.post success handler and see whether you are getting the correct response.

Comment: ajax call did not show the expected results.. i have a div called my ddl.. im showing you the updated code in another comment